# Loading json file and decoding in UTF-16

Tags: python, json, unicode, arabic, utf

This is a better way of wording my question:

I'm trying to read a `utf-16` characters (English and Arabic) from a `.json.gz` file in python 2.7.

The code lines that I have written read `utf-8` characters:

```py
import glob
import json
import gzip

print("Reading input JSON files")
    for filename in glob.glob("*api*.json.gz"):
        with gzip.open(filename,'r') as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

I tried a simple replacement of `utf-8` to `utf-16`, but I got this error:

`ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: CSV files are plain-old text files. They don't require UTF16. Just like any other text file, they can be in any text encoding. In any case, when you call `decode` you specify the *source's* encoding. If that source uses UTF7 you can't use `utf-16`. If you want to save the text into a CSV file you should specify the encoding when writing the text to the file

Comment: I wouldn't make any claims about CSV except that it is text-based, with rows and columns. What encoding to expect depends on the actual flavour, which you must know before writing or reading it. That said, JSON does build on Unicode and is usually represented as UTF-8 or as ASCII (using JSON Unicode escape codes). In either case, your question lacks clarity. Please extract a [mcve] and also include the expected and actual output in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the encoding as a part of `open()`.  Here is a "round-trip demo":

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {
...     "title": "قالت وزارة الداخلية المصرية إن كمية من المتفجرات في سيارة كانت معدة لتنفيذ عملية إرهابية أدت إلى الانفجار الذي وقع وسط القاهرة وأودى بحياة نحو 20 شخصا."
... }
>>> with open("/tmp/utf16demo.json", "w", encoding="utf-16") as f:
...     json.dump(data, f)
>>> with open("/tmp/utf16demo.json", encoding="utf-16") as f:
...     newdata = json.load(f)
>>> next(iter(newdata.values())) == next(iter(data.values()))
True
```

As mentioned in the comments, just because the data is *originally* UTF-16 encoded does not need you mean to *write it back to CSV* in the same encoding.  You are perfectly free to load and decode using UTF-16, but then write out using UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
{"intents": [
    {"tag": "greeting",
     "patterns": ["هاي","عامل إيه","ايه اخبارك","ازيك"],
     "responses": ["هاي!","كويس","حمدالله","ماشي الحال وإنت  ??"],
     "context_set": ""
    }
    ]
}
with open("intents.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
     intents = json.load(f)
```